# Autoload failed to open stream: No such file or directory after disabling extension

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting failed to open stream: etc. ( see below ) . I realise this is a fairly common error , but I'm a bit of a newbie to magento & not sure where go next. It only happens when I try to edit a product or category in the admin panel.

I have:

- disabled all the extensions by renaming the relevant .xml files in app/etc/modules  ( Mirasvit extensions by the way ) .  If I re-enable them I
  don't get any error
- disabled cache , flushed magento cache , disabled
  compilation , recompiled , reindexed , logged out , logged in several
  times.

There is nothing in the theme or anything that is specifically locked into these extensions.

Thanks for your time , your help is greatly appreciated!

```
Warning: include(Mage/Seo/Model/System/Config/Frontend/Category.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

#0 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage/Se...', '/chroot/home/re...', 94, Array)
#1 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Seo_Model_...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Mage_Seo_Model_...')
#4 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1355): class_exists('Mage_Seo_Model_...')
#5 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('seo/system_conf...', Array)
#6 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(365): Mage::getModel('seo/system_conf...')
#7 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(175): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getFrontend()
#8 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#9 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#10 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#11 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#13 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#15 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#16 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(285): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#21 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(250): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#22 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#23 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /chroot/home/returnto/zzz.com/html/index.php(81): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove category seo attribute eav_attribute table: seo/system_config_frontend_category

This is mirasvit plugin migration script;
app/code/local/Mirasvit/Seo/sql/seo_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.4-0.1.5.php: